# Using an Image as the Fill/Texture (not background) of a Plot (not polygon)

Tags: plotting, graphics, image, filling

Is it possible to use an image, rather than a color, or `ColorFunction`, as the filling for a plot?

For instance, I want to make a plot using `DateListPlot`, and have set `Filling->Axis`, and would like the`FillingStyle` to be something other than a solid color, gradient, hatching, or pattern.  Instead, I'd like to use a simple jpg image using `Import`, and then have that image (scaled to fit) be the filling of the plot.  I don't want to use `Overlay` because I only want the image to be the filling from the plotline to axis, nowhere else.

I've also tried using `PlotStyle` along with the `Directive` and `Texture` functions, however this causes the style that I've set for the plot line to be ignored, and the filling to default to white.

I'd show an example of this but can't find any images online, but, let's say I wanted the filling under the curve in this graph:

[image: Example graph]

using this:

[image: Example filling image]

Thanks!

EDIT:  I should mention that I'm using Mathematica 9 on an Mac.

EDIT:  Here is the raw code that produces the graph:

```
DateListPlot[{{{2012, 11, 6, 17, 0, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 18, 0, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 4, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 5, 0.`}, 0.013307611438183348`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 14, 0.`}, 0.015586417157275023`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 32, 0.`}, 0.015644028595458367`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 0, 0.`}, 0.002057611438183348`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 3, 0.`}, 0.03445164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 7, 0.`}, 0.03823044575273339`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 22, 0.`}, 0.04700925147182507`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 30, 0.`}, 0.04578805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 40, 0.`}, 0.04253805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 52, 0.`}, 0.03503805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 5, 0.`}, 0.027538057190916742`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 16, 0.`}, 0.05668208578637511`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 29, 0.`}, 0.04984566862910009`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 33, 0.`}, 0.052624474348191765`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 54, 0.`}, 0.03587447434819177`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 5, 0.`}, 0.032345668629100086`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 11, 0.`}, 0.03312447434819177`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 34, 0.`}, 0.01945164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 50, 0.`}, 0.01720164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 56, 0.`}, 0.019480445752733392`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 0, 0.`}, 0.022259251471825066`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 1, 0.`}, 0.041345668629100094`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 10, 0.`}, 0.03684566862910009`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 13, 0.`}, 0.04590328006728343`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 48, 0.`}, 0.01239402859545837`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 51, 0.`}, 0.016922834314550043`}, {{2012, 11, 7, 0, 36, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 7, 2, 0, 0.`}, 0}}, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {{2012, 11, 6, 17}, 0}, PlotRange -> {{{2012, 11, 6, 16, 15}, {2012, 11, 7, 2}}, {-.009, .0725}}, Frame -> False, GridLines -> False, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> None, Ticks -> {{{2012, 11, 6, 18}, {2012, 11, 6, 19}, {2012, 11, 6, 20}, {2012, 11, 6, 21}, {2012, 11, 6, 22}, {2012, 11, 6, 23}, {2012, 11, 7, 0}, {2012, 11, 7, 1}}, {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07}}]
```

Comment: @Artes That changes the entire background, whereas I want just the background between the plot curve and axis to be different.

Comment: To avoid wasted effort, could you please include the code for the actual `DateListPlot` that you are working with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit: added simpler answer at the end.**

My first answer addresses an issue I would have *wanted* you to have asked about... apparently I was overthinking it. The second answer is the result of actually reading the question (and the comment).

**1. How to make an image background under a specific *segment* of a `DateListPlot`**

You can create an image background by using the `Filling` option to **obscure** an existing background image in those regions where you *don't* want the image to show, and *omitting* any filling where you want the image to be visible.

This is how it can be done in `DateListPlot` (it would be different in `Plot` because there you don't have a list of data that can be partitioned, as I do below). First I'm defining the `data` separately, and also put all the unrelated options into a variable `options` to make the actual plot code easier to read:

```
data = {{{2012, 11, 6, 17, 0, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 18, 0, 0.`}, 
    0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 4, 0.`}, 0}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 5, 0.`}, 
    0.013307611438183348`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 14, 0.`}, 
    0.015586417157275023`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 19, 32, 0.`}, 
    0.015644028595458367`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 0, 0.`}, 
    0.002057611438183348`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 3, 0.`}, 
    0.03445164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 7, 0.`}, 
    0.03823044575273339`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 22, 0.`}, 
    0.04700925147182507`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 30, 0.`}, 
    0.04578805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 40, 0.`}, 
    0.04253805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 20, 52, 0.`}, 
    0.03503805719091674`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 5, 0.`}, 
    0.027538057190916742`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 16, 0.`}, 
    0.05668208578637511`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 29, 0.`}, 
    0.04984566862910009`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 33, 0.`}, 
    0.052624474348191765`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 21, 54, 0.`}, 
    0.03587447434819177`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 5, 0.`}, 
    0.032345668629100086`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 11, 0.`}, 
    0.03312447434819177`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 34, 0.`}, 
    0.01945164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 50, 0.`}, 
    0.01720164003364172`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 22, 56, 0.`}, 
    0.019480445752733392`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 0, 0.`}, 
    0.022259251471825066`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 1, 0.`}, 
    0.041345668629100094`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 10, 0.`}, 
    0.03684566862910009`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 13, 0.`}, 
    0.04590328006728343`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 48, 0.`}, 
    0.01239402859545837`}, {{2012, 11, 6, 23, 51, 0.`}, 
    0.016922834314550043`}, {{2012, 11, 7, 0, 36, 0.`}, 
    0}, {{2012, 11, 7, 2, 0, 0.`}, 0}};

options = {Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {{2012, 11, 6, 17}, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{{2012, 11, 6, 16, 15}, {2012, 11, 7, 
       2}}, {-.009, .0725}}, Frame -> False, GridLines -> False, 
   Ticks -> {{{2012, 11, 6, 18}, {2012, 11, 6, 19}, {2012, 11, 6, 
       20}, {2012, 11, 6, 21}, {2012, 11, 6, 22}, {2012, 11, 6, 
       23}, {2012, 11, 7, 0}, {2012, 11, 7, 1}}, {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03,
       0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07}}};
```

Up to here I just repeated what was defined in the question. Now the actual answer, using the Mona Lisa as a backround image `img`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m6ET.jpg"];

DateListPlot[
 {data[[;; 15]], data[[15 ;; 24]], data[[24 ;;]]},
 options,
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 1 -> Top, 2 -> Top, 3 -> Axis, 3 -> Top}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], White], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Prolog -> Inset[img, {{2012, 11, 6, 20}, 0}, {Left, Bottom}], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: imagePlot]

So all you need to do is divide the `data` into three lists, of which the middle one is the date range where the image should be visible. In the `Filling` option, I then set the first and third segments of the plot to have opaque `White` filling from the curve to the top and to the axis of the plot, which is indistinguishable from the background. For the middle segment, I use the same filling, but only to the `Top` and not to the axis. This leaves the space between the curve and the axis empty and therefore allows a background image to peek through.

Finally, the background image is added using `Inset` inside a `Prologue`. The positioning of the `Inset` had to be adjusted manually to make it look good at the given `ImageSize`. Ideally, you would choose an image that better fits the dimensions of the plot, of course.

In case the actual image you're using ends up showing through below the axis of the plot, you can obscure that part by adding another straight-line data curve with constant value `0` and giving it `Filling` from the curve to the `Bottom`.

**2. Simpler answer to get image under entire curve**

I think I misunderstood the question originally.

The above answer addressed the **partial** appearance of an image under a plot **segment**, as suggested by the example image shown in the question. If the goal is simply to have an image appear under the **entire** plot, it's much simpler:

```
DateListPlot[data, options, Filling -> Top, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], White], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Prolog -> 
  Inset[Show[img, ImageSize -> 500], {{2012, 11, 6, 17}, 0}, {Left, 
    Bottom}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

All I did is to make the bottom left corner of the background image coincide with the axis origin, and set its `ImageSize` equal to that of the plot. Controlling both image sizes explicitly is necessary to retain their relative positioning. The idea behind this method is the same as earlier: use `Filling` to *hide* the unwanted parts of the background.

Now the issue is still that you may want to move the image up and down to make (in this case) the face show up under the relevant part of the curve. Here is a way to do that, using the method I already mentioned in my earlier answer:

```
DateListPlot[
 {data, {{data[[1, 1]], 0}, {data[[-1, 1]], 0}}},
 options,
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> Bottom}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], White], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Prolog -> 
  Inset[Show[img, ImageSize -> 500], {{2012, 11, 6, 17}, -.15}, {Left,
     Bottom}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: mona2]

Comment: Not sure I follow why you only have the image in the center 1/3 of the graph.... how would you make it fill the entire area under the curve?

Comment: I thought your main goal was to show the image only under part of the curve, like the colored regions in the sine plot you showed. If not, things are much easier (see other answers). To make the image fit the entire plot, you of course have to make sure that the aspect ratio of image and plot are identical. This could be done (a) by stretching the image, (b) by choosing an image with the right aspect ratio, or (c) by setting the aspect ratio of the plot equal to that of the image. You'd have to decide first which of these options you want. I mention option (a) in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Since the filling in the original `DateListPlot` is a `Polygon`, you can post-process it to add a texture. The tricky bit is getting the scaling correct - I rescale the polygon coordinates relative to the `PlotRange` (so the texture coordinates run from 0 to 1 across the width and height of the plot) and crop the image to the correct aspect ratio:

```
imagefill[plot_, img_] := Module[{crop, scalefn},
  crop = 
   ImageCrop[img, ImageDimensions[img][[1]] {1, Options[plot, AspectRatio][[1, 2]]}, Bottom];
  scalefn = Transpose @ MapThread[Rescale, {Transpose @ #, PlotRange[plot]}] &;
  Normal[plot] /. Polygon[data___] :>
    {Texture[crop], Polygon[data, VertexTextureCoordinates -> scalefn @ data]}]
```

If `dlp` is your original `DateListPlot` then:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m6ET.jpg"];

imagefill[dlp, img]
```

[image]

Comment: VERY close, the only issue is when I use your code along with mine, the background image and graph are both made roughly 50% transparent.  Perhaps the graph is overlaying a white background on top of the image, making it look lighter than normal, and vice-versa, but the upshot is, yes it puts the image where I want it in the graph, but now both the graph and image are transparent/brightened. Can something be tweaked in `imagefill`?

Comment: @iwantmyphd, I wonder if the filling polygon is partially transparent in version 9. You could try `FillingStyle -> Black`. Otherwise I'm not sure, I don't have version 9 to test with.

Answer (score 9):

```
im2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m6ET.jpg"];

ParametricPlot[{{u, Cos[u]}, ConditionalExpression[{u, v Cos[u]}, -3 Pi/2 <= u <= Pi]},
 {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[1], Texture[ImageMultiply[im2, Yellow]]}],
 AspectRatio -> (1/Divide @@ ImageDimensions[im2]),
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({ #, #2} &), Axes -> {True, False},
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Would you mind using image process?

```
im1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Black}}, 
Axes -> False];
im2 = Import["D:\\MmaSE\\6m6ET.jpg"];(*your image*)
ImageMultiply[ImageAdd[im1, im2], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}]]
```

the output:

[image]

Or there is a RegionPlot approach:

```
RegionPlot[0 < y < Sin[x] || 0 > y > Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, {y, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-1, 1}}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], PlotStyle -> Texture[im2]]
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: I notice that Mona Lisa become fat in RegionPlot approach.

Comment: `ImageMultiply` didn't work, unfortunately, and as you point out, it stretches the image in your example.  `RegionPlot` does look better, however, I need to use `DateListPlot` for this plot, so the `PlotStyle` directive applies to the curve, not the area within.