# da vinci style rendering. of graphics

Tags: graphics

i'm playing with MidJourney AI image generator and, in it there is a da Vinci style that ouputs nicee sketching in parchment simulating the work of our beloved polymath master da vinci: see some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

problem is: MidJourney only knows the usual solids. I would like, for instance to render the Costa's surface using the da Vinci style. I wonder: would it be possible to do that using only withmthematica (I know there is a xkcd style in Matrhematica([xkcd-style Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-plots)) ...

Comment: Hi Humberto, welcome to  Mathematica Stack exchange. Please start by taking the [tour] so you get acquainted with the rules and culture of the site. We expect more from the people asking questions. Check [ask]. Please [edit] your question to tell us more: What have your tried? Why didn't that work?  Share your due diligence! Did you find similar questions on this site? Anything on the documentation that may help? Share code to generate the plot you want styled. And share also code attempts, however unsuccessful, to get the style close to what you want.

Comment: Please focus on the Mathematica programming, *MidJourney AI image* is off-topic here, and we don't need a large gallery of pictures about that. We do need, on the other hand, a well-focused and thoroughly explained programming challenge, that is on-topic.  If you don't [edit] your question to improve it, you risk having it closed or downvoted. Help us curate a good questions that are deserving of good answers.

Comment: Minimum diligence: Start by defining the code that gives you the [CostaMinimalSurface](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CostaMinimalSurface.html) and a way to plot it. Tweak the style on the Mathematica plot as much as possible, Define a background with an image of old paper and text, if you can. From that you could try to enhance it by Fist `Rasterize`, and then `ImageRestyle`. I have **voted to close this question until minimum diligence is shown** in the question.

Comment: friends, I am not an expert in Mathematica! Once i've seen the xkcdMathematica style,  i've  wondered m,y self: iPergaps there was already a code to generate da vinci style ouputs. midjourney is cited gere only to illustrate what i am looking for. soeery if I was unpolite. sorrt for that.

Comment: Costa's surface is just an example indeeded i am looking for a code that ouputs da vinci style of any surface.

Comment: So you are willing to pay for Mathematica just to generate a couple of lovely pictures? Maybe some free tools are better suitable for your goals?

Comment: @yarchikmy university is considering to buy a site license ... iam accepting suggesyions of free tools!  i've tried midjourney ....

Comment: jphaps this is a way:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61341/using-an-image-as-the-fill-texture-not-background-of-a-plot-not-polygon?rq=1 ( da vinci again!)

Comment: [TexturizePolygons](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TexturizePolygons/) with a choice of your sepia-colored images will take you part of the ways there.